# r-value, p-value and standard deviation to inform about non-linear relationship

Tags: regression, python, linear, nonlinear-regression

Is it possible, through the output of the following code, to state that these two variables have a non-linear relationship?

I found this code on the internet along with a statement that there is no linear relationship between these two variables, but I can't understand how to interpret these values to reach the respective conclusion.

```
xi = df['duration']
y = df['next_count']

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(xi,y)

print('r-value', r_value)
print('p-value', p_value)
print('standard deviation', std_err)


r-value 0.051538264501807575
p-value 0.0
standard deviation 1.742321464486595e-05
```

EDIT 1:

```
line = slope*xi + intercept
plot(xi,line,'r-',xi,y,'o')
show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it's possible, but nothing in this unformatted output gives evidence one way or another.

Comment: @AdamO What, then, would be a safe approach to make such a claim that there is or is not a linear relationship?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible. Any values that these statistics can take can be achieved with linear as well as non-linear relationships (so in fact a non-linear relationship is indeed possible, but it's not possible to say with any certainty that the relationship is non-linear). None of these statistics tests linearity, they all *assume* linearity.

Comment: What is the best way, therefore, for me to verify whether or not the relationship between two variables is linear?

Comment: @user14738548 That's a complicateed question because there are many possibilities for non-linearity. Most people would have a look at a scatterplot of the data or fit vs. residuals with more variables, and see whether this looks clearly non-linear. If you want something formal, I'd google for tests of a change point, although this will not find all possible deviations from linearity.

Comment: @user14738548 You can also introduce a squared and/or cubic term into the model and see whether these are significant, but once more, this will not detect all possibilities.

Comment: I just updated my question, adding a plot as you suggested could be a way to analyze the linearity relationship. All my variables plot more or less with these same patterns.

Comment: Didn't you say "these two variables" in the question? Are there more? In that case better do fitted vs. residuals.

Comment: From your plot I'd say non-linearity is the least of your problems. It seems you have lots of zeroes and an extremely skew residual distribution. If your y-variable has counts, Poisson or maybe negative binomial or zero-inflated Poisson regression may be an option.